# The content of column 1 is shown twice what can I do?

Tags: excel, vba

This is a premature version to extract income statement from the web to Excel using VBA:

```
Sub ScrapeMarketWatchgood()
    
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Dim htmlDoc As Object
    Dim tbl As Object
    Dim rowElement As Object
    Dim cellElement As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ExcelTableObjectVariable As ListObject
   
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    
    
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/financials?mod=mw_quote_tab", False
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    xmlhttp.send ""

   
    Set htmlDoc = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
    htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText

    
    Set tbl = htmlDoc.querySelector("#maincontent > div.region.region--primary > div > div.element.element--table.table--fixed.financials > div > div > table")
    
  
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    ws.Name = "Income Statement"

    i = 1

    
    For Each rowElement In tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        j = 1
        For Each cellElement In rowElement.getElementsByTagName("td")
            ws.Cells(i, j).Value = cellElement.innerText
            j = j + 1
        Next cellElement
        i = i + 1 '
    Next rowElement

    
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
    Set htmlDoc = Nothing
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Income Statement")
    
    
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:F100").Cells
        If cell.WrapText Then
            cell.WrapText = False
        End If
    Next cell
     Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Income Statement")
     
    ws.Range("A1:F100").Columns.AutoFit
    ws.Range("A1:F100").Rows.AutoFit
    Set ExcelTableObjectVariable = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ws.Range("A1:F100"), , xlYes)
End Sub
```

[image]

My problem is that column 1 is shown 2 times in the row. I suppose it has to do with how I scraped the table from the web but I cannot find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Extract the content with `Split` for column 1.

```
    For Each rowElement In tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        j = 1
        For Each cellElement In rowElement.getElementsByTagName("td")
            If j = 1 Then
                ws.Cells(i, j).Value = Split(cellElement.innerText, Chr(13))(0)
            Else
                ws.Cells(i, j).Value = cellElement.innerText
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Next cellElement
        i = i + 1 '
    Next rowElement
```

Microsoft reference document:

> [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

[image]

---

Option 2: get the content of column 1 with a child node

```
    Dim cell_content
    For Each rowElement In tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        j = 1
        For Each cellElement In rowElement.getElementsByTagName("td")
            Set cell_content = cellElement.getElementsByClassName("cell__content")
            ws.Cells(i, j).Value = cell_content(0).innerText
            j = j + 1
        Next cellElement
        i = i + 1 '
    Next rowElement
```